# Disjoint union of two affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Say I have two commutative rings with unity, $R$ and $S$.
What does the sheaf of disjoint union of $\DeclareMathOperator{Spec}{Spec}(\Spec(R), \mathscr O_{\Spec(R)})$ and $(\Spec(S), \mathscr O_{\Spec(S)})$ look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a lot like $(\operatorname{Spec}(R\times S), \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R\times S)})$.

Much easier than the bracketed argument is this: The ring of global sections of a disjoint union of ringed spaces is exactly the product of the global sections of the components.  So your disjoint union has $R\times S$ as its global sections—from there, it's an easy guess that it's the affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(R\times S)$.

[In fact, we can intuit this very quickly: the category of affine schemes is dual to the category of commutative rings, i.e. they are essentially the same category, with the arrows reversed.  So $R\times S$, the binary product of $R$ and $S$, should correspond to the binary coproduct of their spectra.]

(It is necessary to verify that the disjoint union really is the binary coproduct in said category, but this turns out to be a good guess.  This is false for infinite disjoint unions, however.)

Comment: The categorical argument has a serious and subtle gap. Find out where. Hint: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics (my answer)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I am aware of the gap—I wasn't trying to word it as a complete argument, and I'll edit for clarity—but I think it's easy enough to patch for _finite_ products.  I suppose the missing fact is that a prime ideal of $R\times S$ corresponds to either a prime ideal of $R$, or a prime ideal of $S$.  To be crystal clear: the _infinite_ coproduct of affine schemes is certainly not the disjoint union.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to make sure that every reader is careful here :). One really has to prove $\mathrm{Spec}(R \times S) = \mathrm{Spec}(R) \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}(S)$ in the category of ringed spaces, there is no fancy categorical argument for this. (There is just a fancy categorical argument for $\mathrm{Spec}(R \otimes S) = \mathrm{Spec}(R) \times \mathrm{Spec}(S)$, using that $\mathrm{Spec}$ is right adjoint.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Well, there's a fancy almost-argument, namely that we can compute limits and colimits in the ambient category of ringed spaces, _if_ the result stays within the (full) subcategory.  So it's enough to show that $\operatorname{Spec} R \coprod \operatorname{Spec} S$ is an affine scheme—then we automatically know _which_ affine scheme it is.  Of course, this is probably less than helpful, because the only non-cohomological way I know of checking that something is affine is to demonstrate an isomorphism with $\operatorname{Spec}$ of its global sections directly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg So I guess this is probably bad even as intuition—at least in this case.  The "hard" part is verifying that the disjoint union is an affine scheme, the "easy" part is computing its global sections.

Comment: I agree to both comments.

Comment: @Slade You said "the ring of global sections of a disjoint union of ringed spaces is exactly the product of the global sections of the components." Does this also work for arbitrary disjoint union or does it only work for finite disjoint union? Thanks!

Comment: @user170778 This also works for an arbitrary disjoint union; it should follow immediately from the sheaf condition.  The difference is that an infinite disjoint union of affine schemes is no longer an affine scheme (or even quasi-compact).  But the global sections are always the product.

Comment: @Slade Got it! Thank you so much for your help!