# Disjoint union of two affine schemes (2)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Very new to algebraic geometry here. In [Disjoint union of two affine schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972367/disjoint-union-of-two-affine-schemes), we see that if $U \cong \text{Spec}(R)$ and $V \cong \text{Spec}(S)$ (as schemes), and then we should have $U \sqcup V \cong \text{Spec}(R \times S)$.

My question is, what is stopping us from assigning random rings to $X :=U \sqcup V$ other than $R \times S$? Say we take $R = S = K$ a field, so $U$ and $V$ are both a singleton. If we define $\mathcal{O}_{X} (X) = \mathcal{O}_{X} (U) = \mathcal{O}_{X} (V) = K$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X} (\emptyset) = 0$, with restriction maps $\text{Res}^X_U = \text{Res}^X_V = \text{id}$, then the composition condition on restriction maps holds, and it seems to me that we do have $\mathcal{O}_{U} = \mathcal{O}_{X}|_U$ and $\mathcal{O}_{V} = \mathcal{O}_{X}|_V$.

My $X$ doesn't seem to look like $\text{Spec}(K \times K)$ (as schemes) like it's supposed to. What conditions am I forgetting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition, $\mathcal O_X$ is not even a sheaf: The sections $1_K\in\mathcal O_X(U)$ and $0_K\in\mathcal O_X(V)$ cannot be glued.

Comment: Ah... I guess I should delete my question later then.

Comment: @diagonal2 No need to.  It's a good question and can be useful to others in the future.